# Misplacement alignment tab character problem

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have no idea why the code returns a warning  error.  I want to align the nomenclature but the equal signs are not aligned under the one column

```
\begin{equation}\label{key}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-v\circ \nabla u-u \left(v \left(\mu _a+\mu _s\right)\right)+\int _{4 \pi }\text{v$\mu $}_sp_s \left(\Omega '\rightarrow \Omega \right)u\left(r,\Omega ',t\right)d\Omega '+q(r,\Omega ,t)
\end{equation}

Where,\\
$u(r,\Omega,\textit{E},t)$      &=  &   angular photon density\\
$t$             &       =   &   time(s)\\
$\mathbit{\Omega}$  &=  &   direction vector of solid angle in steradian\\
$\mathbit{r}$       &=  &position vector\\
$\textbf{v}$        &=  &   speed vector of photon in the medium\\
$\textit{E}$        &=  &   Energy of the photon\\
$\mu_a$             &=  &   absorption coefficients mm^{-1}\\
$\mu_s$             &=  &   scattering coefficients mm^{-1}\\
$p_s\left(\mathrm{\Omega}^\prime\rightarrow\mathrm{\Omega}\right)$  = is the normalized probability of inscattering events of photons from \mathrm{\Omega}^\prime\ to\ \mathrm{\Omega}\\
$q\left(\mathbit{r},\mathbit{\Omega},t\right)$  &= &photon source term including emission events\\
```

[image]

Comment: second row from top big space between & = also second row from bottom I don't see &= & It helps to give a compilable block starting \documentclass{ since there may be prior errors having an effect

Comment: @KJO Thanks but that made no difference

Comment: You can't put `&` tokens on the loose like that. Try adding `\begin{tabular}{lcl}` after ``Where,\\`` and `\end{tabular}` after that block of code.

Comment: When using `tabular`, you don't need to add `\\ ` on the line before it, but do leave a blank line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there were quite a few disparities within such a small block, including the fact the first definition *with an E* does not appear in the current equation.?

I have taken the liberty of restructuring into an align environment, some of my find and replace shortcuts were/are possibly dirty in a hurry.
Revisiting I note there is still a \textit before that first E and unclear if V needs that \textbf

Using {align} requires the \usepackage{amsmath} but that I probably already loaded in your preamble. Revisiting I also note the \text is \texttt if you wish to `find and replace` ttt with t then best to do it in the test copy before you add to your own master file.

If its not to your liking raise a comment and others with more skill can oblige.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{key}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -v\circ \nabla u-u \left(v \left(\mu _a+\mu _s\right)\right)+\int _{4 \pi }\text{v$\mu $}_sp_s \left(\Omega '\rightarrow \Omega \right)u\left(r,\Omega ',t\right)d\Omega '+q(r,\Omega ,t)
\end{equation}

Where,

\begin{align*}
u(r,\Omega,\textit{E},t) &= \texttt{angular photon density}\\
t &= \texttt{time(s)}\\
\Omega &= \texttt{direction vector of solid angle in steradian}\\
r &= \texttt{position vector}\\
\textbf{v} &= \texttt{speed vector of photon in the medium}\\
E &= \texttt{Energy of the photon}\\
\mu_a &= \texttt{absorption coefficients mm}^{-1}\\
\mu_s &= \texttt{scattering coefficients mm}^{-1}\\
p_s \left( \Omega^\prime \rightarrow \Omega \right) &= \texttt{is the normalized probability of inscattering}\\ 
 &~~~~\texttt{events of photons from } \Omega^\prime\ to\ \Omega\\
q\left(r,\Omega,t\right) &= \texttt{photon source term including emission events}\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: is not that is missing. IT is a parameter of u and deliberately left it out to avoid entering a lengthy and cluttered equation. Thanks for the answer!